# Will `String(describing: MyNSObject.self)` always return "MyNSObject"?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uikit

**Will `String(describing: MyNSObject.self)` always return "MyNSObject"?**

Some dev wrote:

```
// identifier is "MyViewController"
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyViewController.self)) as! MyViewController

// identifier is "MyTableViewCell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MyTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
```

Currently it works, because using `String(describing: MyNSObject.self)` is returning `"MyNSObject"`.

But are we in a case of defined behavior or undefined behavior? The documentation of `public init<Subject>(describing instance: Subject)` reads:

```
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `TextOutputStreamable` protocol, the
///   result is obtained by calling `instance.write(to: s)` on an empty
///   string `s`.
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol, the
///   result is `instance.description`.
/// - If `instance` conforms to the `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol,
///   the result is `instance.debugDescription`.
/// - An unspecified result is supplied automatically by the Swift standard
///   library.
```

And I'm afraid that **we may be in the *unspecified result* scenario, aren't we?**

---

Note 1: actual implementation we have is using a `protocol` extension with an implementation close to `static var identifier: String { return String(describing: Self.self) }`.

Note 2: `NSStringFromClass(Self.self as AnyClass).substring(from: NSStringFromClass(Self.self as AnyClass).range(of: ".")!.upperBound)` may be a potential well defined equivalent of `String(describing: Self.self)`, but it looks really ugly.

Note 3: even overriding `description` and `debugDescription` of `MyViewController` and `MyTableViewCell` is apparently not enough to alter `String(describing: Self.self)`.

Currently using Swift 3.1 and will move to Swift 4 when available.

Comment: It would not return "MyView" or "MyViewController" if MyView or MyViewController implement the protocol CustomStringConvertible and override description. 1). so for the first case-"let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: MyViewController.identifier) as! MyViewController
", it might get broken as you set identifier in the storyboard. 2) this one should be working as long as the string used for dequeuing is same as the one when registering the cell, please check out https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/generics/2016/01/06/generic-tableviewcells/

Comment: @MichaelWang overriding description does not affect `String(describing: Self.self)`. Can you try it or show the way that you override it with the described side-effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only official document describing this behavior that I can recall now is found in the Xcode Release Notes:

> #### Swift Enhancements and Changes
>
> - ...
> - Type names and `enum` cases now `print` and convert to `String` without qualification by default. `debugPrint` or
>     `String(reflecting:)` can still be used to get fully qualified names.
>     For example:
>
>   ```
>   enum Fruit { case Apple, Banana, Strawberry }
>   print(Fruit.Apple)      // “Apple”
>   debugPrint(Fruit.Apple) // “MyApp.Fruit.Apple”)
>   ```
>
> (21788604)

(This is in the part of [Xcode 7.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW326) describing the Enhancements and Changes of Swift 1.2 to 2.0 . So, *convert to `String`* means using `String.init(_:)`, now it's `String.init(describing:)`.)

So, some of the core members of Swift were aware of this behavior which was intentionally changed. I expect some discussions in swift.org or at lease some announcement, if Swift team would change it.